# UART - Output Hex Value Without Bitmasks and Shifts?

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded

Easy question:

I'm working on debugging an array of some hex values.  Is there a convenient way to output a hex value over a UART line, without looping through each hex value and using bitmasks and shifts to transmit each bit?

I'm trying to avoid having to write the looping routine, if there is some other way I'm not aware of.  Maybe there is some C magic I don't know?  Some trick here?

**Example Array:**

```
char MyArray[5];

MyArray[0] = 0x55;
MyArray[1] = 0x55;
MyArray[2] = 0x55;
MyArray[3] = 0x55;
MyArray[4] = 0x55;
```

My desired outcome is to just UartSend(MyArray[0]), versus shifting each bit and sending one bit at a time.   Is there some trick to do this?

Trying to save myself an hour of coding up the loop to bitmask this thing.

Comment: How exactly is this hex value stored? What is its data type? Or better yet, can you show the code how you are saving/storing the hex value?

Comment: @HarrySvensson, I updated the question.  Simple Array of 5 chars.  I need the uart to send me each array element.  I could do a loop with bitmasks, but I'm wondering if there is some other simpler way to do it?

Comment: Are you mixing up bits and bytes? - I am not sure if I am seeing the same problem as you are. - Regarding your example array. A hex value has 4 bits, your chars are 8 bits, and you are using all 8 of them. Do you want to send \$55_{16}\$ (two hex value pairs)? Do you want to send \$05_{16}\$ (one hex value per element)? Or do you want to send \$55_{10}\$ in ascii which is \$7_{16}\$? The \$X_{Y}\$ means X in base Y. So the first number of pi in binary would be \$11_2\$

Comment: I want the quick way know MyArray[0] is 0x55.  I was originially to loop through each array element, with so a bitmask, you would loop through MyArray[0] 8 times, take the leftmost bit, send it out the UART, and shift the array element left.  Repeat.  Is there a faster way? I'm not conversant with that ASCII notation...

Comment: `hex` is only a representation of an integer value. ... it is used to simplify the representation of binary values ... example: `bin 10101100` = `hex AC` = `dec 172` ... all three are the same integer value

Comment: Yeah, I get that.  I don't quite get the ASCII syntax (that formal notation), that Harry was calling out. Marko below nailed it on the head what I was looking for.  I usually have bit banged a hex, but it seems most standard embedded have some defined functionality to do the bit banging for you.  I get it'll be slow and the overhead and could trip up an ISR, etc.  Not applicable for my debugging needs here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use printf()

> printf("OutBuf=%02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X\n\r", outbuf[0],
>   outbuf[1], outbuf[2], outbuf[3], outbuf[4],
>   outbuf[5]);

uchar outbuf[6]; // is an arrray

Comment: I've never used printf in an embedded context.  What does that do?

Comment: I'm on an 8051, this looks promising in KEIL: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_lib_stream.htm

Comment: So what did you use before, to send data over UART?

Comment: One bit at a time using a bitmask.  I haven't used UART much.  Usually just simple debugging.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what technique is that, but usually the printf() function is used in C.

Comment: Appreciate the help.  I didn't know this was standard functionality that is tied to the UART in embedded c.  Cheers!

Comment: Find an example in Keil, to setup correctly that the output of putchat() will be tied to the UART. Else it could  transfer those bytes in some other destination.

Comment: I'm going to take the opportunity to plug this super lightweight printf() implementation that I've used on several embedded projects: http://www.sparetimelabs.com/tinyprintf/tinyprintf.php. Should compile to something *much* lighter than whatever the flavour of libc is for your toolchain (seems to be Newlib for most MCU toolchains these days).

Comment: printf is a horrible recommendation for embedded systems. In those systems where it is actually implemented, it will blow up everything that is memory use and execution speed. Maybe once in a while actually look at your own project's map file to see what a mess you made. Plus it is one of the most unsafe functions ever designed, regardless of system. In your example you are printing `int` type (yes! due to the default argument promotions) with `%X` modifier which is strictly speaking undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin It's actually a reasonable recommendation if you work with microchip's toolchain. It has an extremely granular printf implementation, and when building the project it will scan all the code that is linked into the final binary and generate a printf that can handle only exactly what you're asking for. Works surprisingly well, assuming you don't do anything fancy like generating your format strings on-the-fly. Otherwise, yeah, printf is good if you want 30k less code space in your flash.

Comment: @pipe Nah it's really just an excuse to be lazy/not know what you are doing. Writing a minimal functionality UART driver is not rocket science. And converting raw binary numbers to ASCII hex should not be much of a challenge for the average beginner still learning programming.

Comment: Well... I don't know if converting ASCII hex is high on my bucket list when I urgently just need to get the output of some of these array elements at 3AM.... ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a convenient way to output a hex value over a UART line, without looping through each hex value and using bitmasks and shifts to transmit each bit?

UART couldn't care less about the format of the data. Just send it. What are you actually asking here, how to make an UART output appear as ASCII in a terminal program?

That's fairly trivial, just use a look-up table on nibble basis. Example:

```
const char HEX [16] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
uint8_t array [5] = {0x11,0x22,0x33,0xAB,0xFF};

for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof array/sizeof *array; i++)
{
  uart_send(HEX[(array[i] >> 4) & 0x0F]);
  uart_send(HEX[array[i] & 0x0F]);
}
```

---

> `char MyArray[5];` ... `MyArray[0] = 0x55;`

You should *never* use the `char` type for storing anything else but character letters. The reason is because it has implementation-defined signedness, so you can't know from compiler to compiler if it is signed or not. If it is signed, hex values of 0x80 or higher will cause all manner of nasty bugs.

Professional embedded system programs *always* use the types from `stdint.h`, in this case it would be `uint8_t`

Comment: I'd caveat, that KEIL has some serious limitations using PrintF on a char too. I monkeyed with it for awhile.  I couldn't cast it as an int.  Not to be pedantic, but technically you are using a bitmask there and loop, which I was trying to not code up.  A very nice snippet though.  Appreciate it!

Comment: @Leroy105 It will be very hard to code something more effective and safe, completely free from crap. Though you could write this whole program at compile-time, if you don't use variable indata.

Comment: I agree on the completely free from crap. It was nearly 1KB of additional code to implement printf.  I'd probably not use printf (which is why I've never heard of it used in this context... who knew...?).  I was debugging some serious-bug causing insane issues, buffer overflow, overflowing in an ISR, and my MCU doesn't support debugging in an ISR.  Quick and dirty, is the name of the game.  I typically don't use many outside libraries (particularly klutzing around with those 8051 in this case, Cortex M is a different story).  Trust me -- I'll stockpile that snippet in my cache. ;)

Comment: But I will say, printf, in a pinch -- vs. setting up a UART interrupt, confirming the timing with whatever else your system is doing, 
 add it in, etc, etc, etc... depends on the context.

Comment: PS:  I would say my context is an RF device, oversampling a signal over the air (so you have a TX and an RX to contend with being a candidate), with no debugger in an ISR, and what appears to be an overflow in one function, subtling breaking but not killing your system.  I'm looking at this with clean'er eyes and moved variables around to idata and xdata.  Seems to have fixed this subtle breakage.  Can I get a UART debugger output, stat...!